# How to configure Spring controller test to only use selected configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

I've set up a Spring controller test that also checks for security configuration. The security configuration is externalised so in my test I need both the controller class (as a component), and the separate security config. So far, I've annotated my test class this way:

```
@WebMvcTest
@SpringJUnitWebConfig({MyWebController.class, SecurityConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(printOnlyOnFailure = false)
public class MyWebControllerTest {
    //tests go here
}
```

This seems to work fine when I run the tests on my local environment (macOS), but when I push the changes that the CI build (Ubuntu) eventually runs against, it fails. The failure is caused by a code that runs past the security configuration; the assumption is that it should not even have to guard against the failure because the security configuration should have prevented the flow to get to that part. Now, I can simply update the production code to do the checks, however, I'd also like to address the part where the test doesn't seem to honour the configuration when it's run on Ubuntu.

Comment: `@WebMvcTest` should already pikcup your security config. DOing `@WebMvcTest(MyWebController.class)` should be all you need.

Comment: Not explicitly stating that I only need those 2 things causes Spring to try and configure all other things I'm not interested in (database config, etc.)

Comment: That shouldn't happen with `@WebMvcTest`, so there must be something in your test that you aren't showing. It should only bootstrap a minimal config with only the web related parts. So basically there is something bigger wrong with your testcase. Or your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class has embedded config (or uses `@Import` for other parts.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The issue with unnecessary things being loaded into the test context is due to the Spring boot app having annotations similar to those. Moving those annotations to a separate config (and clearing up the annotations in my test) seems to have solved the issue.